# Как в проекте менять версии Python внутри venv (на Windows 10)

Tags: python, virtualenv, venv

у меня Windows 10. Я не использую среду разработки PyCharm. Я использую блокнот Jupyter Notebook.

**(1)** Сначала я просто скачал с официального сайта инсталлятор `python-3.8.10-amd64.exe` и установил его обычным способом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге Питон установился куда я и просил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**(2)** Далее я создаю папку `test1` для своего проекта и перехожу в неё в командной строке:

```
cd C:\Users\alexw\Desktop\test1
```

И создаю тут виртуальное окружение:

```
C:\Users\alexw\Desktop\test1> python -m venv env
```

в итоге в директории `test1` вижу поддиректорию `env`

Активирую окружение:

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

в результате в командной строке перед командой появляется надпись `(env)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**(3)** Проверяю версию Питон:

```
python --version => Python 3.8.10 (как и ожидалось)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**(4)** Далее ставлю любую нужную библиотеку, нужной версии (правильную команду смотрю на сайте **pypi.org**), например:

```
pip install requests==2.27.0
```

Смотрю версию командой `pip list` и убеждаюсь что она **2.27.0**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**(5)** Далее например мне надо проверить на другой версии. Ставлю другую версию:

```
pip install requests==2.25.1
```

Убеждаюсь что версия поменялась:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, я так понял, в Питоне любая вновь установленная версия библиотеки *"перезатирает"* предыдущую версию в данном виртуальном окружении. Ну хорошо. Вроде понятно.

Сейчас такая проблема: Мне теперь надо протестировать некие скрипты не просто на разных версиях библиотек, а еще и на разных версиях интерпретатора Питон.

Например, в данный момент у меня в виртуальном окружении **Питон 3.8.10** (см. пункт **(3)** ). А сейчас мне нужна версия **Python 3.9.8**. Причём мне в принципе не важно, что там глобально установлено, мне именно в моём текущем виртуальном окружении `env` это надо, чтобы я мог при желании менять версии интерпретатора Питон одной командой, как я сейчас меняю одной командой текущие версии библиотек.

Подскажите плиз, как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подскажу способ без привлечения разных дополнительных иснструментов, т.к. сам ими не пользуюсь. Можно посмотреть в сторону pyenv и poetry для этого.

**Я бы делал так:**

1. Придется в любом случае установить в системе нужные версии интерпретаторов. Тут важно понимать что такое переменная среды PATH в Windows.
   PATH — это системная переменная, содержащая список директорий, в которых ОС будет искать исполняемый файл при вызове команды из консоли. Именно благодаря ей можно запустить интерпретатор, просто вбив `python` в консоли в любом месте.

В Windows 10 можно добраться до настройки PATH так: Этот компьютер → Свойства → Дополнительные параметры системы → Дополнительно → Переменные среды.

У меня путь до одной из версий есть в этой переменной, до остальных
нет и для их запуска требуется указывать полный путь.

2. Нужные зависимости можно устанавливать через файл requirements.txt.

Получить список установленных библиотек:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Этот файл можно поправить вручную.
Потом создать в отдельной папке новое виртуальное окружение, привязанное к нужной версии питона и там установить через файл эти библиотеки

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

А именно менять версии интерпретаторов для venv не выйдет. Во всяком случае я таких способов не знаю. Venv ссылается на интерпретатор и зависит от него.

Answer (score 0):

У меня похожая проблема, мне надо было поменять версию интерпретатора с `3.11.3` на `3.12`.

для того, чтобы это сделать, достаточно заново ввести команду для создания *venv* в *cmd*:

```
python -m venv env
```

предварительно указать путь к папке, в которой вы хотите произвести изменения.